# Image gallery out of range

Tags: html, css, image

I'm setting up some HTML site and I added this image to gallery (already on) but when I add it, it's getting out of range. How do you fix this?

[See the red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvhsn.jpg)

```
</div>
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Commodities/onions.jpg" alt="onions" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Onion</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Commodities/Potato.jpg" alt="Potato" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Potatoes</div>
</div><div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Commodities/Garlic.jpg" alt="Garlic" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Garlic</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Commodities/sugar.jpg" alt="Sugar" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Sugar</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Commodities/greenpeas.jpg" alt="Green peas" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Green peas</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<h4 style=" background:#bbbbbb;"><br />Spices<br /></h4>
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/Spices/CorianderSeeds.jpg" alt="CorianderSeeds" width="110" height="90"></a>
    <div class="desc">Coriander Seeds</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
```

Comment: You have additional markup like `br` and `h4` that ruins the flow of the images. If it is not neccessary, try to remove them.

Comment: Can u put a working demo for this?

Comment: I'm Sorry.Still I didn't Understand anything,Can you please explain more?